# All values in array pointer being modified upon function call

Tags: arrays, c, list, pointers, hashtable

So, I have this hashtable data structure based on a linked list data structure:

```
//linked list node  

struct node{
    char* symbol;
    int weight;
    struct node* succ;
};
typedef struct node node;

//linked list 

struct linkedList{
    node* head;
};
typedef struct linkedList linkedList;

//hashtable  

struct hashTable{
    linkedList* cells;
    int capacity;
};
typedef struct hashTable hashTable;
```

I'm trying to implement an insertion function for the hashtable. At the moment, the code for the function (and the function it calls, insertion_linkedList) is the following:

```
//linked list insertion

void insertion_linkedList(linkedList* l, node n){
    node** p = &l->head; 
    if (*p == NULL){
        *p = &n;
    }
    else{
        while ((*p)->succ != NULL){
            *p = (*p)->succ;
        }
    }
    (*p)->succ = &n;
    return;
}


//hashtable insertion 

void insertion_hashTable(hashTable h, char* s, int n){
    node ins = {.symbol = s, .weight = n, .succ = NULL};
    insertion_linkedList(&h.cells[hashFunction(s, h.capacity)], ins);
}
```

For some reason which I don't understand, whenever I try to insert a new node into a hashtable data structure, all of the previously inserted values are also modified to the values corresponding to the most recently added node. See:

```
int main(){
    int cap = 100;
    hashTable h = creation_hashTable(cap);

    insertion_hashTable(h,"b",4);
    insertion_hashTable(h,"a",1);
    insertion_hashTable(h, "c", 2);

    printf("%i\n", h.cells[hashFunction("b",h.capacity)].head->weight);
    // !! returns 2 and not 4 !!

    exit(0);
}
```

Honestly, I don't really understand what's happening here (I'm guessing that it's something to do with residual pointer values?) Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
*p = &n;
```

and

```
(*p)->succ = &n;
```

`&n` is a pointer to a local variable (function parameter) - an object with [automatic storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/lifetime). This pointer is invalid as soon as the function returns, at which point dereferencing it invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

See also: [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

For your linked list to scale in any meaningful way, you need to use [dynamic memory allocation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory) to extend the lifetime of the objects you are placing in the lists / tables.

A cursory example would be:

```
void insertion_linkedList(linkedList *l, node n) 
{                                                                                  
    node *new = malloc(sizeof *new);
    /* byte-wise copy of `n` to the memory pointed at by `new` */
    *new = n;
        
    if (!l->head)
        l->head = new;
    else {                             
        node *current = l->head;              
                                              
        while (current->succ)                 
            current = current->succ;                                               
                                              
        current->succ = new;
    }
}
```

These pointers to dynamically allocated objects must later be passed to [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free).